# Passing multiple types to std::function C++

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am currently working on a little library and ran into a error. What I am basically trying to do is have syntax like so:

```
Client client("", true);

client.on("ready", [](User object) {
    object.test();
});

client.run();
```

and when I call
`_eventManager->emit("ready", new User())`
The `client.on();` method is suppose to fire with the given object I pass in. The object that I pass can be a variety of classes.

The way I design it so that I use a base class called "Object" and all the classes that I want to pass onto `emit` would be derived from `Object`. However I get an error when trying to do this:

`error C2664: 'void Discord::Client::on(const std::string &,const std::function<void (Discord::Object)> &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'main::<lambda_54cb69ba8322d42f33e22a0f4f4926a4>' to 'const std::function<void (Discord::Object)> &'
2>  z:\projects\visual studio 2015\discord\test\source\example1.cpp(12): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'main::<lambda_54cb69ba8322d42f33e22a0f4f4926a4>' to 'const std::function<void (Discord::Object)>'
2>  z:\projects\visual studio 2015\discord\test\source\example1.cpp(12): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called`

I am clueless on what I did wrong.
Code:

```
struct Event {
    std::string name;
    std::function<void(Object object)> function;
};

void Client::on(const std::string& name, const std::function<void(Object object)>& function) {
    _eventManager->add(name, function);
}

void Client::run() {
    User object;

    _eventManager->emit("ready", object);
}

void EventManager::add(const std::string& name, const std::function<void(Object object)>& function) {
    Event event;
    event.name = name;
    event.function = function;

    _events.push_back(event);
}

void EventManager::emit(const std::string& name, const Object& object) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _events.size(); i++) {
        Event& event = _events[i];

        if (event.name == name) {
            event.function(object);
        }
    }
}
```

[Error](http://prntscr.com/ffqsc8)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `User` inherited from `Object`?

Comment: Yes. `class User :public Object {}`

Comment: How are class Object and class User related?

Comment: You pass an `Object` to the lambda, how do you expect a `User` to be created from that?

Comment: Because they are inherited maybe.

Comment: What inherirs what? If User inherirs Object, then how do you know that the lambda that expects a User will be indeed called with a reference to Userm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is declared to take `Object` object:

```
std::function<void(Object object)> function;
```

but you pass lambda that takes `User`:

```
client.on("ready", [](User object) {
    object.test();
});
```

Is this what you are looking for?

```
client.on("ready", [](Object object) {
    auto& user = static_cast<User&>(object);  // not safe
    user.test();
});
```

Note that this might crash your app if you try to access any field that belongs to `User` class but not to `Object` class (it's probably an undefined behaviour) since passing by value "slices" data. What you should probably do is pass pointers/refs around:

```
client.on("ready", [](Object& object) {   // <-- by ref here
    auto& user = static_cast<User&>(object);  // safer, at least won't crash when you pass User object
    user.test();
});
```

Note that this requires some major refactoring. Not only adding `&` everywhere but you now have to worry about lifetimes of those objects.

Comment: "No suitable conversion from Object to User exists". Also shouldn't `class User :public Object {}` allow me to send `User` instead of `Object`?

Comment: @Kurieita Oh, right, you actually have to cast to `User&` (I've updated the answer). It would probably be wiser to pass pointers or references as arguments instead of values. Anyway passing `User` instead of `Object` is not the same as passing `std::function<void(User)>` instead of `std::function<void(Object)>`. C++ won't allow this "deep" type of inheritance.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, but it works. Thank you.

Comment: @freakish casts can solve most problems if your goal is to get your software to compile. If you want it to run, it's a whole different bunch of hedgehogs.

Comment: @n.m. Any other solution would probably require some major refactoring of the code. Maybe it has to be done. Maybe not. It's up to OP. I'm only giving a solution to the problem. I'm not saying that the static_cast is the best solution. But I'm also not saying it is bad. "Is sword dangerous? Or is it a samurai who wields it?".

Comment: Lol, what would be a better solution for what I want to do?

Comment: @Kurieita probably by making `Event` and `EventManager` template classes, e.g. `template<typename T> class Event { std::string name; std::function<void(T)> function; };` and then pass around `T` type.

Comment: How is `static_cast<User&>(object)` even supposed to work, given that `object` is passed by value and has been sliced? It's no longer a `User`. This smells of UB. I think the right fix is for the functions to be `std::function<void(Object&)>` and then we want to `dynamic_cast<User&>` to make sure that we actually were even passed a `User`.

Comment: @cdhowie That's why I said the he should pass pointers or references. Perhaps I should add this to the answer itself.

Comment: Would I also pass the template class for `Client::on(string, T)`?

Comment: @Kurieita That depens on your design. I don't really know what `Client` class is. But I assume you have an `EventManager` field inside? You could define it like `EventManager<User> _eventManager;`. Or possibly make entire `Client` class a template. There's no *one* way to do that. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @freakish if what you propose works, then nothing more is needed, the problem is, you don't know if it's going to work, nor does anyone else without a thorough analysis of the entire system.

Comment: To make things clear, I'm not saying your solution is bad or suboptimal, only saying that its potential limitations need be pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Can also try something like the below.. I made the parameters pointers to prevent Slicing, but the actual solution to the issue is the `createFunc` function which binds the passed in lambda to an internal one that calls the passed in lambda. It ensures that the classes passed in are derived from `Object`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class Object;

struct Event {
    std::string name;
    std::function<void(Object* object)> function;
};

class Client
{
private:
    std::vector<Event> events;

public:
    void on(const std::string& name, const std::function<void(Object* object)>& function)
    {
        this->events.push_back(Event{name, function});
    }

    void run()
    {
        for (Event &e : events)
        {
            e.function(nullptr);
        }
    }
};


class Object
{
};

class User : public Object
{

};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Object, T>::value, std::function<void(Object*)>>::type
createFunc(std::function<void(T*)> func)
{
    auto call = [](std::function<void(T*)> func, Object *ptr)
    {
        func(dynamic_cast<T *>(ptr));
    };

    return std::bind(call, func, std::placeholders::_1);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Client c;

    auto lambda = [](User* usr) {
        std::cout<<"Lambda called\n";
    };

    c.on("Hello", createFunc<User>(lambda));
    c.run();

    return 0;
}
```

`CreateFunc` is essentially the same as:

```
template<typename T>
void callFuncHelper(std::function<void(T*)> func, Object *ptr)
{
    func(dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr));
};


template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Object, T>::value, std::function<void(Object*)>>::type
createFunc(std::function<void(T*)> func)
{
    return std::bind(callFuncHelper<T>, func, std::placeholders::_1);
}
```

and works like:

```
Client c;

auto lambda = [](User* usr) {
    std::cout<<"Lambda called\n";
};

c.on("Hello", createFunc<User>(lambda));
c.run();
```

Why? Because I couldn't find another way to deduce the lambda parameter so you have to pass it in as a template argument.

Comment: Thanks for that, it helped alot. Is it possible to remove `createFunc` tho? That's the only thing I don't like about your example lol

Comment: @Kurieita You can do that by moving the `createFunc` internals to `Client::on` as a template function: http://ideone.com/9maoJG  Then you'd have to do: `client.on<User>("Hello", lambda)`

Comment: Never, ever, *ever* use `reinterpret_cast` to move in a hierarchy of derived classes. Not even once. It is dangerous, it is not guaranteed to work, and it will *always* break the moment you start using multiple inheritance.

Comment: Fixed. Uses `static_cast`.

Comment: One should prefer dynamic_cast if possible, for its clean and predictable failure mode. `static_cast` works when it works, but when it doesn't, you are not going to get any hint of what went wrong.

Comment: Can I get an example using `dynamic_cast`

Comment: @Kurieita; Just replace `static_cast` with `dynamic_cast`.. Since `dynamic_cast` returns `NULL` upon failure, you should check in your event handler (your lambda) whether or not the pointer is null.